# Using tar, the entire folder structure is including, I don't want that

Tags: tar, compression

I am taring a folder and for some reason the entire directory structure that preceds the folder I am tarring is included.

I am doing this in a script like:

```
'tar czf ' + dir + '/asdf.tgz ' + dir + 'asdf/'
```

Where dir is like:

```
/Downloads/archive/
```

In the man pages, I see I can fix this but I can't get it to work.

I tried:

```
tar czf -C dir ...
```

But now I have some kind of a file -C in my folder (which I can't seem to delete btw!).

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The single-character options must be followed immediately by their parameters, then any other parameters. Otherwise, use normal style options or combine the `-C` the same way:

   ```
   tar cvCf dir asdf.tgz asdf
   tar -c -v -f dir/asdf.tgz -C dir asdf
   ```
2. Since programs read `-` as meaning an option character, you need to defeat this to access a file starting with `-`. Two ways to do this:

   ```
   rm -- -C
   rm ./-C
   ```

Comment: I'm getting a failed to open '~/path/to', here is my command: `tar czfC ~/path/to/asdf.tgz asdf/`

Comment: That command doesn't look right; as written you have told it to use archive `~/path/to/asdf.tgz`, then change directory to `asdf/`, but no files to add to the archive (which should produce an error message).

Comment: ok I don't understand why the order matters, I thought cvCf are just options that you are passing, compress, verbose, f etc...

Comment: C and F both want pathname arguments.  They don't mean the same thing, so you'd kinda like to know which name goes with which option, yes?

Comment: @Blankman or just change to the dir first. `cd ~/Downloads/archive/ && tar -czf asdf.tar.gz asdf/`